# Copy of paper by M. Naimi on squarefree friable integers

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, paper-request

I am trying to get a hold on a copy of a 1988 paper by M. Naimi. It appears in MR as [MR0950949](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0950949) and in zbMATH as [Zbl 0669.10066](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0669.10066). Its title is "Les entiers sans facteurs carré $\le x$ dont leurs facteurs premiers $\le y$". It was published in Publications Mathématiques d'Orsay, vol. 88, as part of a book it seems.

On the [Publ. Math. Orsay website](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/PMO/) it seems there is no information on the paper or volume.

Any help on getting a copy would be appreciated. I have tried contacting the author directly but that didn't help.

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply trying to put [Naimi "Les entiers sans facteurs carré"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Naimi+%22Les%20entiers%20sans%20facteurs%20carr%C3%A9%22) into Google leads to a [PDF file](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/39_SEMINAIRE/pdf/39_SEMINAIRE.pdf) which contains the corresponding volume of *Publications Mathématiques d'Orsay* - including this article.

It seems that some other volumes are available on the same site - I have tried a few similar links: [38](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/38_SEMINAIRE/pdf/38_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [37](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/37_SEMINAIRE/pdf/37_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [26](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/26_SEMINAIRE/pdf/26_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [15](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/15_SEMINAIRE/pdf/15_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [04](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ebiblio/numerisation/docs/04_SEMINAIRE/pdf/04_SEMINAIRE.pdf). However, I failed to find a page which contains some kind of archive linking to those pdf-s. (Still, Google indexed them, so the crawler must have discovered them somewhere.)

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I did various searches on Google Scholar, but next time will make sure to google on Google itself.

Comment: I agree that it is a bit surprising that it is among the search results here but not in Google Scholar - I have only tried Google Scholar after your comment, so basically I was just lucky that I tried to search in this way. (At least I have learned that sometimes it might be useful to try both.)

Comment: [01](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/01_SEMINAIRE/pdf/01_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [04](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/04_SEMINAIRE/pdf/04_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [07](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/07_SEMINAIRE/pdf/07_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [09](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/09_SEMINAIRE/pdf/09_SEMINAIRE.pdf), [11](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/11_SEMINAIRE/pdf/11_SEMINAIRE.pdf), ... seems a bit random

Comment: @MartinSleziak Link seems dead now unfortunately. I do have a backup of the file locally, but wonder whether you can find an alternative source for others who are interested in this work. (I didn't manage.)

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky I did not find a working link either. I have [mentioned this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2023/3/24) - on the off chance that somebody who visits that chatroom might have some other idea where to search.